# How to Access Arrays with a JSON Hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

So I am trying to access the "country_code" field, but it is an array within the :businesses hash, so I have no idea how to access it/make it a hash to access it

```
{:message=>{"text"=>"OK", "code"=>0, "version"=>"1.1.1"}, :businesses=>[{"rating_img_url"=>"http://media1.ct.yelpcdn.com/static/201012164084228337/i/ico/stars/stars_4.png", "country_code"=>"US",


    obj = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse("http://url")).body).to_options
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
obj[:businesses][0]['country_code']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
country_code = obj[":businesses"][0].country_code
```

Comment: i tried displaying this variable and i got this:


undefined method `businesses' for #<Hash:0x00000100f55ef0>

Comment: Hmm..I guess it's because of the ":".  That's funky. Update to what I think might work.